# How to make the plot smooth

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

There are some stranges point which cause the figure isn't smooth. I think that the reason is the method of numericial integration. Here is my code, it's pleasure that one can revise the drawbacks in the code.

```
zslist = Table[0.8999 - i/480 0.8999, {i, 0, 99}];  
ϵ := 0.000001;
zc = 10^-2;
d = 4;   
Do[z0[i_, d_] := 
  zslist[[i]] - ((1 - zslist[[i]]^d) ϵ^2)/(2 zslist[[i]]);
  z1[i_, d_] := -(((1 - zslist[[i]]^d) ϵ)/zslist[[i]]);
  s[i, d] = 
  NDSolve[{z''[ρ] == -((
   2 z[ρ]^3 Derivative[1][z][ρ]^2)/(
   1 - z[ρ]^4)) + (-(2/z[ρ]) - 
     Derivative[1][z][ρ]/(ρ (1 - z[ρ]^4))) (1 - 
     z[ρ]^4 + Derivative[1][z][ρ]^2), 
  z[ϵ] == z0[i, d], z'[ϵ] == z1[i, d]}, 
  z, {ρ, ϵ, 10}];
  f[ρ_, i_, d_] := s[i, d][[1, 1]][[2]][ρ];
  r[i_, d_] := 
  FindRoot[f[ρ, i, d] == zc, {ρ, 
  s[i, d][[1, 1]][[2]][[1, 1, 2]]}][[1, 2]];,
  {i, 1, Length[zslist]}]  
TabzsR = Table[{r[i, d], z0[i, d]}, {i, 1, Length[zslist]}];  
ListPlot[TabzsR, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]  
Clear[zsR]  
zsR[x_] := Interpolation[TabzsR][x];  
Rmax = r[3, d]  
Rmin = r[99, d]  
△l = (Rmax - Rmin)/360  
Rlist = Table[Rmax - △l i, {i, 0, 359}];  
Do[zn0[i_, d_] := 
  zsR[Rlist[[i]]] - ((1 - zsR[Rlist[[i]]]^d) ϵ^2)/(
  2 zsR[Rlist[[i]]]);
  zn1[i_, d_] := -(((1 - zsR[Rlist[[i]]]^d) ϵ)/
  zsR[Rlist[[i]]]);
  sn[i, d] = 
  NDSolve[{
   z''[ρ] == -((
   2 z[ρ]^3 Derivative[1][z][ρ]^2)/(
   1 - z[ρ]^4)) + (-(2/z[ρ]) - 
     Derivative[1][z][ρ]/(ρ (1 - z[ρ]^4))) (1 - 
     z[ρ]^4 + Derivative[1][z][ρ]^2), 
  z[ϵ] == zn0[i, d], z'[ϵ] == zn1[i, d]}, 
  z, {ρ, ϵ, 10}];
  fn[ρ_, i_, d_] := sn[i, d][[1, 1]][[2]][ρ];
  ,
  {i, 1, Length[Rlist]}]
δ = 10^(-7);  
Do[Dfn[i_, 
  d_] := -((fn[ρ, i, 
     d] /. {ρ -> Rlist[[i]] - δ}) - ( 
   fn[ρ, i, 
     d] /. {ρ -> Rlist[[i]] - 1.001 δ} ))/(δ - 
  1.001 δ);
  D2fn[i_, 
  d_] := -((D[
     fn[ρ, i, d], ρ] /. {ρ -> 
      Rlist[[i]] - δ}) - ( 
   D[fn[ρ, i, d], ρ] /. {ρ -> 
      Rlist[[i]] - 1.001 δ} ))/(δ - 1.001 δ);
  fnp[ρ_, i_, d_] := 
  zc + Dfn[i, d] (ρ - Rlist[[i]]) + 
  D2fn[i, d] (ρ - Rlist[[i]])^2/2 ;
  rArea[i_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ρ/fnp[ρ, i, d]^2 Sqrt[
  1 + D[fnp[ρ, i, d], ρ]^2/(1 - 
      fnp[ρ, i, d]^4)], {ρ, Rlist[[i]] - δ, 
  Rlist[[i]]}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] + 
  NIntegrate[ρ/fn[ρ, i, d]^2 Sqrt[
  1 + D[fn[ρ, i, d], ρ]^2/(1 - 
      fn[ρ, i, d]^4)], {ρ, 0, Rlist[[i]] - δ}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30] - Rlist[[i]]/zc;, {i, 1, Length[Rlist]}]  
TabrAreaR = Table[{Rlist[[i]], rArea[i, d]}, {i, 1, Length[Rlist]}];  
ListPlot[TabrAreaR, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Joined -> True]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't produce a plot as written. It is also too long as it is, so it is too demanding to ask us to wade through it and find the errors for you. Please reduce it to a *much smaller* minimal working example so that we may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I think the reason is from the `NIntegrate`, there are many warning messages about `NIntegrate`.

Comment: I  can obtain the two plots.  I recommend that you delete `WorkingPrecision -> 30` from `NIntegrate`, because it does not increase accuracy and generates numerous warning messages.  Because the integrands are smooth, it seems unlikely that the irregularities arise from `NIntegrate`.  More likely, the irregularities are associated with the finite differences that feed into the integrands.

Comment: How do you get the right plot? I delete `WorkingPrecision -> 30` as you said, there are still the irregularity.  And how to improve the inetgrand to decrease the feedback due to the finite differences?

Comment: @amonxu It is difficult to try to improve your code without knowing what you are trying to accomplish.  For instance, why are you using finite differences to construct `Dfn` instead of taking the second derivative?

Comment: This can be learned from the experience of one of the authors of the paper, i.e.   `Applying a polynomial expansion for fn[\[Rho],i,d] using the solution, does not solve the issues of the divergences by itself. The derivative will diverge anyway.
Try rather a polynomial expansion of the form a + b (\[Rho]-R) + c (\[Rho]-R)^2, where you fix the coefficients a, b, c by 
(1) constructing the derivative by hand using the numerical solution, but making sure that the derivative does not explode, or,
(2) plugging them into the equation of motion and solving them order by order in \[Rho].  `

Comment: `In the end, you have to make sure that the total boundary (numerical solution + expansion) is of the same order as the area of the string surface in pure AdS (last number in the list).`

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to answer the question, I

- Rationalized all constants.
- Used `WhenEvent` to stop `DSolve`before `z'[ρ]` becomes singular.
- Solved for both `z` and `z'` in the second instance of `DSolve` to improve the accuracy of the integrand of the subsequent `NIntegrate`.
- Commented out the instance of `NIntegrate` involving `fnp`, which has no significant effect on the results.
- Tried `Method -> "DoubleExponential"` and (`"LocalAdaptive"` also) to improve results of `NIntegrate`.
- Experimented with increased `WorkingPrecision`.

Only the last of these had any substantive effect, and then not the expected one.  Below is the code with `WorkingPrecision` not set.

```
ϵ = 10^-6; zc = 10^-2; d = 4; δ = 10^-7; imax = 100; imaxn = 360;
zslist = Table[(1 - i/480) 8999/10000, {i, 0, imax - 1}];

Do[z0[i_, d_] := zslist[[i]] - ((1 - zslist[[i]]^d) ϵ^2)/(2 zslist[[i]]);
   z1[i_, d_] := -(((1 - zslist[[i]]^d) ϵ)/zslist[[i]]); 
   NDSolve[{z''[ρ] == -((2 z[ρ]^3 z'[ρ]^2)/(1 - z[ρ]^4)) + (-(2/z[ρ]) - 
            z'[ρ]/(ρ (1 - z[ρ]^4))) (1 - z[ρ]^4 + z'[ρ]^2), 
            z[ϵ] == z0[i, d], z'[ϵ] == z1[i, d], 
            WhenEvent[z[ρ] == zc, r[i, d] = ρ; "StopIntegration"]}, 
            z, {ρ, ϵ, 10}], {i, 1, imax}];
TabzsR = Table[{r[i, d], z0[i, d]}, {i, 1, imax}];  
ListPlot[TabzsR, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"r", "z0"}]  

zsR[x_] = Interpolation[TabzsR][x];  
Rmax = r[3, d] ; Rmin = r[imax - 1, d] ; △l = (Rmax - Rmin)/imaxn ;
Rlist = Table[Rmax - △l i, {i, 0, imaxn - 1}];

Do[zn0[i_, d_] := SetPrecision[zsR[Rlist[[i]]] - ((1 - zsR[Rlist[[i]]]^d)
                               ϵ^2)/(2 zsR[Rlist[[i]]]), 15];
   zn1[i_, d_] := SetPrecision[-(((1 - zsR[Rlist[[i]]]^d) ϵ)/zsR[Rlist[[i]]]), 15];  
   sn[i, d] = NDSolve[{z''[ρ] == -((2 z[ρ]^3 z'[ρ]^2)/(1 - z[ρ]^4)) + (-(2/z[ρ]) - 
                    z'[ρ]/(ρ (1 - z[ρ]^4))) (1 - z[ρ]^4 + z'[ρ]^2), 
                    z[ϵ] == zn0[i, d], z'[ϵ] == zn1[i, d], 
                    WhenEvent[z[ρ] == zc, "StopIntegration"]}, 
                    {z, z'}, {ρ, ϵ, 10}];
   fn[ρ_, i_, d_] := z[ρ] /. First@sn[i, d]; 
   fnd[ρ_, i_, d_] := z'[ρ] /. First@sn[i, d], {i, 1, imaxn}]

Clear[rArea, fnp];
Do[(*fnp[ρ_,i_,d_]:=zc+fnd[Rlist[[i]]-δ, i, d] (ρ-Rlist[[i]])+(D[fnd[ρ, i, d],ρ]
         /.ρ->Rlist[[i]]-δ) (ρ-Rlist[[i]])^2/2;*)
    rArea[i_, d_] :=(* NIntegrate[ρ/fnp[ρ,i,d]^2 Sqrt[1+D[fnp[ρ,i,d],ρ]^2/
         (1-fnp[ρ,i,d]^4)],{ρ, Rlist[[i]]-δ,Rlist[[i]]}]+*)
            NIntegrate[ρ/fn[ρ, i, d]^2 Sqrt[1 + fnd[ρ, i, d]^2/(1 - fn[ρ, i, d]^4)], 
            {ρ, 0, Rlist[[i]](*-δ*)}, Method -> "DoubleExponential"] 
            - Rlist[[i]]/zc, {i, 1, imaxn}]; 
TabrAreaR = Table[{Rlist[[i]], rArea[i, d]}, {i, 1, imaxn}] ;
ListPlot[TabrAreaR, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Rlist", "rArea"}, Joined -> True]
```

This code produces the plots,

[image]

[image]

The irregularities described in the question are apparent in the second plot.  Running the code with the commented items uncommented produces the same plots.

If the only issue were the noisy second plot, the irregularities could be removed by

```
ListPlot[MovingAverage[TabrAreaR, 20], Joined -> True, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Rlist", "rArea"}]
```

However, while experimenting with the code, I found the second plot to be quite sensitive to seemingly minor changes.  For instance, increasing the precision of `zn0` and `zn1` from `15` to `20` and adding `WorkingPrecision ->20` to `NIntegrate` and the second instance of `NDSolve` yields for the second plot.

[image]

Thus, both instances of the second plot are not only noisy but, probably, wrong.  The fundamental difficulty is this: `fn` approaches zero at the upper bound of `NIntegrate`, and as a consequence the integrand approaches infinity.  A typical plot of `fn` is

```
Plot[fn[ρ, 215, 4], {ρ, 0, Rlist[[215]]}, AxesLabel -> {"ρ", "fn"}]
```

[image]

It is not difficult to show that `fn` varies as Sqrt[ρ0 - ρ] near where `fn` vanishes, designate `ρ0`.  I leave it to someone more knowledgeable than I to obtain a final answer.